# Screen recording a specific window with audio

Tags: python, audio, windows, screen-recorder

Raspberry Pi / Python. I need to be able to capture a specific tkinter window with audio, if the specified window is not possible then a predefined area of the screen is.
We are currently using SimpleScreenRecorder to perform this function, however, it means starting up a separate program, pointing to the window, and starting the recording. etc.
I need to be able either program this function or use a screen recorder with CLI that includes options for a specific window.
The goal is to have "Record Start" and "Record Stop" buttons as part of my program and the rest be automatic.
Help would be much appreciated.